# Linux kernel parameters - Update thermal module passive and critical values dynamically

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to update the kernel parameters listed in below link. Specifically I want to update Thermal parameter values (`thermal.psv` and `thermal.crt`). I understood that this can be used using kernel command line from the link given below.

**My Analysis and issue I am facing now**

As per the link given below, thermal module should be there in `/sys/module` directory in Linux. But I dont see Thermal module in `/sys/module` directory. Please help me if there is any way to set `thermal.psv` and `thermal.crt` values though kernel command line and also why is that I am not seeing Thermal module in `/sys/module`.

List of module available in my Linux PC directory `/sys/module` given in this image:

[image]

kernel parameters: [documentation on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)

Comment: On all my machines available the thermal options are compiled directly into the kernel instead of into a module. Is this actually a physical machine, or a VM?

Comment: What problem are you solving by tuning these? Do your CPUs run hot enough that they shut off?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It is a physical machine

Comment: @JohnMahowald you are correct. CPU getting heated up and  closing few applications.